# Does there exist any linear function $f$ such that $\forall a, b, c \in \mathbb{R}^n: (a-b)\cdot c=a\cdot f(a, b, c)$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Does there exist any linear function $f$  such that $\forall a, b, c \in \mathbb{R}^n: (a-b)\cdot c=a\cdot f(a, b, c)$ ?

And if so, how can one such function be found?

"$\cdot$" denotes the scalar product. The closest I got is $f(a,b,c)=c-\frac{a}{a^2}(b\cdot c)$ which is obviously not linear in $a$ but I am looking for a function linear in $a$, $b$ and $c$.

Edit: 
Since it's not possible if $a$ can be the zero-vector, does adding the condition that $a\neq 0^n$ make the problem solvable? ($0^n$ being the n-dimensional zero-vector)

Comment: Let $a=0$ and $b=c\neq 0$.  Then on the left you have $(0-b)\cdot b = -\|b\|\neq 0 = 0\cdot f(a,b,c)$ regardless of the choice of $f$.

Comment: As an aside, in your "*attempt*" you used a fraction... what do you mean by $a^2$?  What do you mean by $\frac{a}{a^2}$?  Remember that $a$ is a vector in $\Bbb R^n$.  As far as I can tell your expression is meaningless and you were treating them as though you were working in $\Bbb R^1$.

Comment: I meant $\frac{a}{a^2} = a\times{\frac{1}{a\cdot a}}$ which is the vector multiplied by the inverse of the square of its 2-norm. I don't see how that would be a problem in $\mathbb{R}^n$. About the $a=0$ case: is it possible to solve when adding the condition that $a$ is not the zero-vector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Element-wise, we have

$$\sum_{i=1}^N (a_i-b_i)c_i = \sum_{i=1}^N a_i f_i$$

First, assume that each $f_i$ only depend on $a_i,b_i$ and $c_i$. Then, we must have that:

$$f_i(a_i,b_i,c_i) = c_i - \frac{b_i c_i}{a_i}$$

which is what you had found before and not linear in $a_i$. This means that if there exists an $f$, linear in $a$, then each entry $f_i$ must be a function of some other entries of $a,b,c$.

However, since the RHS is a weighted sum of the $f_i$ with $a_i$ as weights, I don't see how there can be a general solution $f$ that depends linearly on $a$, unless you know something more about the vectors $a,b,c$.

Comment: It's not clear to me how the fact that it's not possible to be solved component-wise can be used to show that it's also not possible without that restriction. However, since your answer answers the question by prooving it's not possible for $n=1$, I'll have to accept it. Still curious about $n$ greater than 1 though.

Comment: I showed that each element of $f$ only depends on $a_i,b_i,c_i$. Thus, if $f$ is linear in $a$, $f_i$ would need to be linear in $a_i$, but this fails. Thus, $f$ cannot be linear in $a$.

Comment: Note that $u\cdot v = w\cdot z$ means $u_1v_1+\dots+u_nv_n=w_1z_1+\dots+w_nz_n$ and is not equivalent to $u_iv_i=w_iz_i$ for $i=1,\dots,n$.

Comment: Thanks @Christoph, you are right. I edited my answer to take that into account. I still don't see how there could be a general solution that is linear in $a$ unless there are constraints on what $a,b,c$ can be.